# Debian packaging of Python code

Tags: python, debian, packaging

I am trying to create a debian package of my Python code, but I am very confused about some fields in `debian/control` files. Namely, what

`X-Python-Version`, `XS-Python-Version` and `XB-Python-Version` stands for?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It is described here: https://www.debian.org/doc/packaging-manuals/python-policy/ch-module_packages.html

> The optional X-Python-Version (preferred) or XS-Python-Version field in the general paragraph (the first one, for the source package) of debian/control specifies the versions of Python (not versions of Python 3) supported by the source package. Similarly, X-Python3-Version is used to specify the versions of Python 3 supported by the package.
>
> The use of XB-Python-Version in the binary package paragraphs of debian/control file has been deprecated and should be removed

So you should only use X-Python-Version and perhaps X-Python3-Version.

To specify what version of Python is required to **build** your package, you want `Build-Depends` as described here: https://www.debian.org/doc/packaging-manuals/python-policy/ap-build_dependencies.html

For example:

```
 Build-Depends: python (>= 2.6.6-9)
```

Comment: But what does it mean? Do I specify with X-Python-Version a python version, which is neccessary in order to __build__  a package? Then how do I specify a minimum version of Python which is supported to run my package.

Comment: I suppose it's the version of Python required to run your package.  Most packages don't require Python to build them, right?

Comment: Most don't, but mine does so how to say express that?